# playFramework 2.4 and guice 3

Tags: playframework, sbt, guice

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/issues/51

> I'm using the libraries in a playframework 2.4 project, which uses
>   Guice 4.0. When I try to create a new AdWordsServices object, I'm
>   running into version related problems:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ImmutableList
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        ... 65 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?